# Let $f(\lambda) =\lambda^4 - 4\lambda^2 + 2 \in \mathbb{Q}[\lambda]$, let $E$ be the splitting field, find $E$ and $[E : \mathbb{Q}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, splitting-field

> Let $f(\lambda) =\lambda^4 - 4\lambda^2 + 2 \in \mathbb{Q}[\lambda]$, and let $E$ be the splitting field of $f$. Find $E$ and $[E : \mathbb{Q}]$.

I found the hint of this question very confusing. The hint says "Show that $E$ is generated by a single root of $f(\lambda)$ in $E$". But I do as the following

Find out all roots of $\lambda^4 - 4\lambda^2 + 2$, which are $\pm \sqrt{2 \pm \sqrt{2}}$. I don't think $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}]$ and vice versa. So $E=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}]$ and $[E : \mathbb{Q}] = 2$.

Seems like my solution contradicts to the hint, what is going wrong? Also how is this question related to $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: $[E:\mathbb{Q}]$ is definitely not $2$.  $\text{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ is the Klein $4$-group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Batominovski: Hmm. I would have thought that the Galois group is cyclic? Didn't check the argument yet. But Klein 4 would imply the existence of 3 quadratic intermediate fields and I only see one.

Comment: Sorry, it is cyclic as Jyrki said.  I had an extra automorphism of order two which wasn't correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to prove that $E=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt2})$. A step-by-step way could be:

1. Show that $\sqrt2\in \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt2})$.
2. Check that $\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}=\sqrt2$.
3. Show that $\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}\in\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt2})$.
4. Rejoice.

Comment: Step 2 can be viewed as an extension of the trick showing that $\sqrt3-\sqrt2$ is an element of the field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)$.